# Match datetime format with Bash REGEX

Tags: regex, bash, datetime

I have data with this datetime format in bash:

`28/11/13 06:20:05` (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss)

I need to reformat it like:

`2013-11-28 06:20:05` (MySQL datetime format)

I am using the following regex:

```
regex='([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])\s([0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])'

if [[$line=~$regex]]
then
   $line='20$3-$2-$1 $4';
fi
```

This produces an error:

```
./filename: line 10: [[09:34:38=~([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])\s([0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])]]: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE:

I want to read this file "line by line", parse it and insert data in mysql database:

'filenameX':

```
27/11/13 12:20:05 9984 2885 260 54 288 94 696 1852 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 13:20:05 9978 2886 262 54 287 93 696 1854 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 14:20:05 9955 2875 262 54 287 93 696 1860 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 15:20:04 9921 2874 261 54 284 93 692 1868 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 16:20:09 9896 2864 260 54 283 92 689 1880 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 17:20:05 9858 2858 258 54 279 92 683 1888 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 18:20:04 9849 2853 258 54 279 92 683 1891 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 19:20:04 9836 2850 257 54 279 93 683 1891 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 20:20:05 9826 2845 257 54 279 93 683 1892 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 21:20:05 9820 2847 257 54 278 93 682 1892 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 22:20:04 9810 2844 257 54 277 93 681 1892 32 88 27 7 154
27/11/13 23:20:04 9807 2843 257 54 276 93 680 1892 32 88 27 7 154
28/11/13 00:20:05 9809 2843 257 54 276 93 680 1747 29 87 17 6 139
28/11/13 01:20:04 9809 2842 257 54 276 93 680 1747 29 87 17 6 139
28/11/13 02:20:05 9809 2843 256 54 276 93 679 1747 29 87 17 6 139
28/11/13 03:20:04 9808 2842 256 54 276 93 679 1747 29 87 17 6 139
28/11/13 04:20:05 9808 2842 256 54 276 93 679 1747 29 87 17 6 139
28/11/13 05:20:39 9807 2842 256 54 276 93 679 1747 29 87 17 6 139
28/11/13 06:20:05 9804 2840 256 54 276 93 679 1747 29 87 17 6 139
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start!"

while IFS='     ' read -ra ADDR;
do
   for line in $(cat results)
   do
      regex='([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9]$
      if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
         $line="20${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
      fi
      echo "insert into table(time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values('$line', '$line', '$line', '$line', '$line');"
   done | mysql -user -password database;
done < filenameX
```

Result:

time                | total | caracas | anzoategui |
0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 9     | 9       | 9          |
2027-11-13 00:00:00 | 15    | 15      | 15         |

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Because `date` has many formatting options that will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: This answer was accepted based on fixing the bash-focused approach in the OP. For a simpler, `awk`-based solution see the last section of this answer.

Try the following:

```
line='28/11/13 06:20:05' # sample input

regex='([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])'

if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
  line="20${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
fi

echo "$line"  # -> '2013-11-28 06:20:05'
```

As for why your code didn't work:

- As @anubhava pointed out, you need at least 1 space to the right of `[[` and to the left of `]]`.
- Whether `\s` works in a bash regex is platform-dependent (Linux: yes; OSX: no), so a single, literal space is the safer choice here.
- Your variable assignment was incorrect (`$line = ...`) - when *assigning* to a variable, never prefix the variable name with `$`.
- Your backreferences were incorrect (`$1`, ...): to refer to capture groups (subexpressions) in a bash regex you have to use the special `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` array variable;  `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` contains the entire string that matched, `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` contains what the first capture group matched, and so on; by contrast, `$1`, `$2`, ... refer to the 1st, 2nd, ... argument passed to a shell script or function.

---

**Update**, to address the OP's updated question:

I *think* the following does what you want:

```
# Read input file and store each col. value in separate variables.
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15; do

    # Concatenate the first 2 cols. to form a date + time string.
    dt="$f1 $f2"

    # Parse and reformat the date + time string.
    regex='([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])'
    if [[ "$dt" =~ $regex ]]; then
      dt="20${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi

    # Echo the SQL command; all of them are piped into a `mysql` command
    # at the end of the loop.
    # !! Fill the $f<n> variables in as needed - I don't know which ones you need.
    # !! Make sure the number column name matches the number of values.
    # !! Your original code had 4 column names, but 5 values, causing an error.
    echo "insert into table(time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values('$dt', '$f3', '$f4', '$f5');"

done < filenameX | mysql -user -password database
```

---

**Afterthought**: The above solution is based on improvements to the OP's code; below is a streamlined solution that is a one-liner based on `awk` (spread across multiple lines for readability - tip of the hat to @twalberg for the awk-based date reformatting):

```
awk -v sq=\' '{
 split($1, tkns, "/");
 dt=sprintf("20%s-%s-%s", tkns[3], tkns[2], tkns[1]); 
 printf "insert into table(time,total,caracas,anzoategui) values(%s,%s,%s,%s);", 
   sq dt " " $2 sq, sq $3 sq, sq $4 sq, sq $5 sq
}' filenameX | mysql -user -password database
```

Note: To make quoting inside the `awk` program simpler, a single quote is passed in via variable `sq` (`-v sq=\'`).

Comment: @nandophillips: added an explanation

Comment: @nandophillips: Sounds like a problem with your MySQL statement string - try with a single command on the command line until you get it right, then fix the script.

Comment: @nandophillips You need to split the - reformatted - line into tokens to create your SQL insert command; I can help you later.

Comment: @nandophillips: Take a look at the updated code; moved the `mysql` command outside the loop; broke all input lines into individual fields; addressed the column-value-count mismatch; read the `!!` comments to make the SQL insert command do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Perl is handy here.

```
dt="28/11/13 06:20:05"
perl -MTime::Piece -E "say Time::Piece->strptime('$dt', '%d/%m/%y %T')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T')"
```

```
2013-11-28 06:20:05
```

Comment: +1 for this multi-platform solution - though use in a loop may cause performance issues; on OSX (but, sadly, not Linux), you can use `date` with  `-f` to describe the input format: `date -j -f '%d/%m/%y %T' +'%Y-%m-%d %T' "$dt"`. As for performance: running the conversion 100 times results in the following times (the absolute times are not important, but their ratios are): Perl: 3.55s; date (OSX): 0.51s; Bash regex: 0.34s.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick without any overly complicated regex invocations:

```bsh
echo "28/11/13 06:20:05" | awk -F'[/ ]' \
    '{printf "20%s-%s-%s %s\n", $3, $2, $1, $4}'
```

Or, as suggested by @fedorqui in the comments, if the source of your timestamp is `date`, you can just give it the formatting options you want...

Comment: +1; re `date`: the OP's input date format doesn't work with `date -d` on Linux (GNU date 8.13; even with locales where this format is used), but on OSX you could use the following, because the input format can be specified explicitly: `date -j -f '%d/%m/%y %T' +'%Y-%m-%d %T' '28/12/13 06:20:05'`.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are mandatory in BASH so use:

```
[[ "$line" =~ $regex ]] && echo "${line//\//-}"
```

Also you cannot use `\s` in BASH so use this regex:

```
regex='([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])'
```

Comment: It still not reformating and drop '2028-11-13 00:00:00' :(

Comment: Actually, whether `\s` works is platform-dependent; e.g.: Linux: yes; OSX: no.

Comment: @nandophillips: You probably didn't copy paste my regex right. See **working demo: http://ideone.com/uCEgE0**

Comment: `\s` does not work for me in Linux or OS X. As far as I know, Perl-style `\x` sequences are not supported in `bash`.

Comment: @chepner: try `re='\s'; [[ ' ' =~ $re ]] && echo YES`. (Only works if used via a variable, sadly.) If that doesn't work for you, please tell me what Linux platform you're on.

Comment: @chepner: The `=~` is an unfortunate case where a native bash feature is platform-dependent, because it uses the platform-specific regex libraries. In the case of Linux you get _some_ of what Perl supports: `\s`, `\w` and their negations work, but `\d` doesn't, for instance; Linux doesn't support `\b`, only `\<` and `\>`; in Perl, it is the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for the sample above.

> "T" not appended

```
$line='"2020-11-26 10:20:01.000000","the size of the table is 3.5" (inches)","2020-12-11 10:20:02"'
$echo "$line" | sed -r 's#(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})#\2T\1#g'
"2020-11-26 10:20:01.000000","the size of the table is 3.5" (inches)","2020-12-11 10:20:02"
```

> "T" appended only to middle of first column and not any other column with date format in the row

```
$awk '/[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]*/{print}' test_file |sed -e 's/\s/\T/'
"2020-11-26T10:20:01.000000","the size of the table is 3.5" (inches)","2020-12-11 10:20:02"
```

> example from above with grouping

```
$ line='"2020-11-26 10:20:01.000000","the size of the table is 3.5" (inches)","2020-12-11 10:20:02"'
$ regex='([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])'
$ if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then line="20${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}T${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"; fi
$ echo "$line" 
2026-11-20T10:20:01
```

#...the intention is to append "T" between date and time (same field) on all fields within huge csv file with millions of records, not just first column, all having same date format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS